# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in Node js with Express

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm using a local `.json` file as database for my small web appplication. It works without issues and I can retrieve data from it, but when I look to the console I see the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined...` appearing twice each time. The error is not consistent and I can't properly replicate it and I don't understand what may cause it.

**JSON**

```
{
  "Faction1": {
    "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "id": "lorem-ipsum",
    "content": {
      "colors": {
        "col1": "red",
        "col2": "white",
        "col3": "grey"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
    //jshint esversion:6
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const favicon = require('serve-favicon');

    const app = express();

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.use('/scripts', express.static( __dirname + '/node_modules/'));


    const factionsDb = require(__dirname + '/views/data/factions.json');

    JSON.stringify(factionsDb);

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.render('pages/index', {
      pageTitle: "App Name"
      });
    });


    app.get('/factions', (req, res) => {
      res.render('pages/product-list', {
        parentPage: "'/'",
        pageTitle: "Factions",
        section: "factions",
        productsList: factionsDb
      });
    });

    app.get('/factions/:productId', (req, res) => {
      let requestedProductId = req.params.productId;

      let selectedProduct = Object.values(factionsDb).find(product => Object.values(product).includes(requestedProductId));

      res.render('pages/product-details', {
        parentPage: "'../factions'",
        pageTitle: selectedProduct.name,
        section: "factions",
        product: selectedProduct
      });
    })

    app.listen(3000, function(){
      console.log("Server started on port 3000");
    });

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

    app.use(function (req, res) {
        res.status(404).render('pages/404', {parentPage: "'/'", pageTitle: ""},
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you select nonexisting product, then `selectedProduct` will be `undefined`:

```
let selectedProduct = Object.values(factionsDb).find(product => Object.values(product).includes(requestedProductId));
```

Then you try to set following `pageTitle: selectedProduct.name,`, which goes into `selectedProduct` variable and tries to find object `name` in it. As the selectedProduct is undefined, it throws error you mentioned.

You should be able to simulate it by calling URL with some nonssense `:productId`, i.e. `/factions/nonexistingfaction`

Comment: Object 'name' is always specified in json, and selected product is always defined, I don't understand why it doesn't find it, also navigation still proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Need to check if there is matched item by find function.

`let selectedProduct = Object.values(factionsDb).find(product => Object.values(product).includes(requestedProductId));

If there is no matched item, it will return undefined So try to check selectedProduct.

Below I have updated pageTitle part.

```
  res.render('pages/product-details', {
    parentPage: "'../factions'",
    pageTitle: (selectedProduct && selectedProduct !== undefined)?  selectedProduct.name : '',
    section: "factions",
    product: selectedProduct
  });
```

Sync:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file', 'utf8'));
```

Async:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj;
fs.readFile('file', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Comment: This is weird because navigation is always by existing products, the database is static and there isn't a case where I search for a non existing product. I inserted your modification and now it tells me 'Cannot read property 'id' of undefined' in the console (used in the product-details template)

Comment: Try to apply same way to check for id property usage. It's not exactly match hence you did got that error So try to check that matching product codebase again.

Comment: If I put `console.log(selectedProduct.name);` before the `res.render` it always shows the correct name property, but also the error right after, so I don't know why it does not find it. I discovered that this error appears mostly on the first time and after brief periods of inactivity, might be some kind of performance problem?

Comment: Yes. I agree. Please try to update JSON import part to asynchronous and check.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I have updated answer with async/sync operations for json file reading.